# access violation in converting string to double with atof

Tags: c++, access-violation

I used atof to convert from string to double. The program reads from the csv file one string by one string till eof is reached. Only at a particular string has problem with access violation and those strings before don't have any problem. What could be the problem? The error is 
Unhandled exception at 0x778515de in TestOpenCV_CameraCalibration.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x406e64b1. It happened at atof.
The program is attached below

```
 while (!myReadFile.eof()) 
       {
           //myReadFile>>cstr;
           getline ( myReadFile, cstr, ',' );
           //removedString = RemoveChars(cstr, removedchar);
           const char * c = cstr.c_str();
           //cout << k << "\n";
           if(k == 1200)
               k = k;
           temp[j++][k] = atof(c);
           if(i < 3)
           {
               if((j = j % 2) == 0) 
                   k++;
           }
           else
           {
               if((j = j % 3) == 0) 
                   k++;
           }
       }
```

Comment: Either `j` or `k` is too big.

Comment: @cnicutar I believe so too, but notice, `k` is bounded to 1200, `j` is from 0 to 2? There must be something wrong with `temp`'s boundaries

Comment: @Aniket There's nothing in that code bounding either one of those.

Comment: `if(k == 1200) k = k;` <- wrong it should probably be `if(k == 1200) k = 1199; `?

Comment: @cnicutar `j = j % 3` <- folds all values between 0 and 2

Comment: @Aniket Right! I Didn't notice it was actually assigning, I stand corrected.

Comment: @Bryanyan please post more code - a Short compilable program

Comment: Please provide a minimal, compilable testcase. Minimal means "using only essential code to reproduce the problem". Compilable means "able to compile on our systems without filling in blanks or fixing syntax errors". Without a minimal, compilable testcase, there is no guarantee that we can help you. The worst case scenario is that your problem is elsewhere, which means that any attempt to help you would be wasteful of our time. The best case scenario is that your problem is in this code, but we have to guess repeatedly to solve it. That's inoptimal use of our time.

Comment: Yes j is normally from 0 to 1 or 0 to 2. if (k == 1200) is for my debugging purpose. But access violation happened when k reached to 1846. The array length is 2 x 5000 (2D array).I will pose the whole code soon.

Answer (score 0):

consider using [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/)

read the value into a double

compare the endptr to your char ptr.  If they are the same, don't increment your counters.